# Calculate Final Due Date In JavaScript From Term

Tags: javascript, date, math

I need to find a way to calculate the final due date of a loan using JavaScript, but need to account for months with less than 31 or 30 days.

For example, if I have a term of 60 months (5 years) and my start_date is 01/31/2015, my final due date would be 12/31/2019.  Now, if my term was 62 months, my final due date would be 02/28/2020.  The problem with most JavaScript math is that I get a result of 03/03/2020 which is not correct.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there only unusual behavior when the date of the month is 29, 30, or 31?

Comment: Yeah, hard coded exception seems to be the fastest way, as Scott is suggesting.

Comment: Thanks All!  @ScottSauyet suggestion worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not well-tested, but it might do what you want.  It involves redoing some of the calculations that the Date API does automatically, but they're not too difficult:

```
var addMonths = (function() {
  var counts = {
    normal: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    leap:   [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
  };
  return function(startDate, months) {
    var endYear = startDate.getFullYear() + Math.ceil((months + startDate.getMonth()) / 12) - 1;
    var yearType = ((endYear % 4 == 0) && (endYear % 100 != 0)) || (endYear % 400 == 0) ? 'leap' : 'normal';
    var endMonth = (startDate.getMonth() + months) % 12;
    var endDate = Math.min(startDate.getDate(), counts[yearType][endMonth]);
    return new Date(endYear, endMonth, endDate);
  };
}());

var date = new Date(2015, 0, 31); // 2015-01-31
addMonths(date, 60); //=> 2020-01-31
addMonths(date, 61); //=> 2020-02-29
addMonths(date, 62); //=> 2020-03-31
addMonths(date, 63); //=> 2020-04-30
addMonths(date, 73); //=> 2021-02-28
```

Note that my numbers seem to be a month off from yours.  I'm guessing you're using a first-payment as your start date, and not actually adding a full complement of, say, 62 months to it.  But obviously this would be easy to adjust by one if you so desired.

Answer (score 0):

Add the number of years and months you want, then find the last day of that month. Javascript date addition will give you the results you found so it takes a couple of extra steps:

```
function addMonths(month, year, term) {
    var endTerm = term - 1;     // adjust for zero index
    var newYear = year + parseInt(endTerm / 12); // add the years
    var newMonth = month + (endTerm % 12);  // add the remaining months
    if (newMonth > 12)  {     // remaining months into next year?
        newYear = newYear + 1;  
        newMonth = newMonth - 12;
    }
    var endDate = new Date(newYear, newMonth, 0); // get last day of month
    return endDate;
}
```

This solution meets the parameters you set.  You'll need to check for corner cases.  For example, a term of 1 month gives an end date of the current month, a term of 2 months gives an end date of next month.

This is a very simple solution for your specific problem. If you're going to do a bunch of date manipulation then consider using a library.

Here's a real quick jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8gnb0s0s/3/